# Nullpointerexception with JPanel

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jpanel

When I m trying to call panel2 inside actionPerformed method, I m getting nullpointerexception. Plz help me in getting out of this silly prblm.

```
public class PanelEventTest implements ActionListener {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
     JFrame frame;
     JPanel panel1, panel2;
     String[] list = {"Sachin","Tarun","Vipin"};
     JList jlist;
     JButton next;

     void originalFrame()
     {
         frame = new JFrame();
         frame.setSize(500, 300);
         frame.setVisible(true);
         frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
         frame.add(panel1());
         frame.add(panel2());
     }

     JPanel panel1()
     {
         panel1 = new JPanel();
         next = new JButton("Next");
         next.addActionListener(new PanelEventTest());
         panel1.add(next);
         return panel1;
     }

    JPanel panel2()
    {
         panel2 = new JPanel();
         jlist = new JList(list);
         panel2.add(jlist);
         panel2.add(new JLabel("Test"));
         return panel2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new PanelEventTest().originalFrame();
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e.getActionCommand() == "Next")
        {
            panel2.removeAll();
        }
    }
 }
```

action event is not attached with panel2, is that a reason behind this exception?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. kindly update your question with error stacktrace

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
next.addActionListener(new PanelEventTest());
```

you should have

```
next.addActionListener(this);
```

Otherwise, the event listener will be *another* instance of PanelEventTest, whose `originalFrame()` method has never been invoked, and whose `panel2` variable is thus null. (Note that even if its `originalFrame()` method was called, it would remove everything from its *own* panel2, and not from the panel2 of the frame containing the button).

You should prefer using (annonymous) inner classes for your listeners instead of making the frame itself a listener:

```
next.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        panel2.removeAll();
    }
});
```

Comment: @Sachin Lal and to use [CardLayout(bunch of examples about next and previous button)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) instead of remove and add new JPanel

Comment: TY for the help, my this problme is resolved nw. My Next Question is if I make three classes one for originalFrame, one for Panel1 and one for Panel2 then how to implement/call/pass the event?

Comment: I have pasted the code @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986208/nullpointerexception-continues plz check it out guys.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

`next.addActionListener(this);`