# NullPointerException continues

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jpanel

When I am trying to call JPanel panel2 of Panel2 class on triggering of action event from Next JButton of Panel1 class, I am getting NullPointerException. How to resolve this? plzz help.

```
public class PanelEventTest
{

/**
 * @param args
 */
JFrame frame;

void originalFrame()
{
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(500, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.add(new TestPanel1().panel1());
    frame.add(new TestPanel2().panel2());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    new PanelEventTest().originalFrame();
}
}

public class TestPanel1
{
JPanel panel1;
JButton next;

JPanel panel1()
{
    panel1 = new JPanel();
    next = new JButton("Next");
    next.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new TestPanel2().panel2.removeAll();
        }
    });
    panel1.add(next);
    return panel1;
}
}
public class TestPanel2
{
JPanel panel2;
JList jlist;
String[] list = {"Sachin","Tarun","Vipin"};
JPanel panel2()
{
    panel2 = new JPanel();
    jlist = new JList(list);
    panel2.add(jlist);
    panel2.add(new JLabel("Test"));
    return panel2;
}
}
```

My last question [Nullpointerexception with JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979304/nullpointerexception-with-jpanel) was successfully resolved by you guys. Plz help in this. This exception is eating my head.

Comment: Check the answer's code now, I believe it is complete.

Comment: Yes, it got resolved nw cmpletely. Ty man...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try changing this line:

```
new TestPanel2().panel2.removeAll();
```

To:

```
new TestPanel2().panel2().removeAll();
```

Will solve the problem, but the current logic is flawed.

### A better solution is:

Change `TestPanel2` to:

```
public class TestPanel2 {
    JPanel panel2;
    JList jlist;
    String[] list = { "Sachin", "Tarun", "Vipin" };

    public TestPanel2() { // was: JPanel panel2() {
        panel2 = new JPanel();
        jlist = new JList(list);
        panel2.add(jlist);
        panel2.add(new JLabel("Test"));
                      // was: return panel2;
    }
}
```

And then modify `TestPanel1` to:

```
public class TestPanel1 {
    JPanel panel1;
    JButton next;

    public TestPanel1(final JFrame frame, TestPanel2 tp2) { // was: JPanel panel1() {
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        next = new JButton("Next");
        final JPanel panel2 = tp2.panel2; // line created
        next.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                panel2.removeAll(); // was: new TestPanel2().panel2.removeAll();
                frame.validate(); // line created
                frame.paint(); // line created
            }
        });
        panel1.add(next);
                         // was: return panel1;
    }
}
```

Finally, on `PanelEventTest.originalFrame()`, change:

```
frame.add(new TestPanel1().panel1());
frame.add(new TestPanel2().panel2());
```

to:

```
TestPanel2 tp2 = new TestPanel2();
frame.add(new TestPanel1(frame, tp2).panel1);
frame.add(tp2.panel2);
frame.validate();
frame.repaint();
```

### Explanation

You are creating methods, when you needed constructors. You **must** read this: [Understanding constructors](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-10-2000/jw-1013-constructors.html).

Also, you need to pass `TestPanel2` and the `frame` to `TestPanel1`:

- Your code was creating a new `TestPanel2` (attached to no one) and then calling `removeAll()` on it's pannel. This has no effect at all (as this panel is not shown anywhere).
- The changed then code will call `removeAll()` on `TestPanel1`'s panel.
- Also, you need to revalidate/repaint the components everytime you make a change on them.

  - Currently you change them when you create the `frame` (adding the panels) and when you remove the `panel2` (in the "Next" button's action).

Comment: Ty v much fr this help. My all prblms got resolved nw. Very helpful advice given to me.